# Incorrect behaviour of author abbreviation using biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, citing, acronyms

I want to use biblatex-apa with biber-backend to create a bibliography. I use the shortauthor-tag, so that the **full names of the organizations only appear once, and only abbreviations afterwards**. This seems not to work, when I fist cite both publications at the same time in a multiple citation, as shown in the MWE below.

I am using **biber v2.11** and **biblatex v3.11** (installed via MiKTeX 2.9.6730 on Win10).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sortlocale=de_DE]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{BMG2018, BLS2011} \\

\parencite{BLS2011} \\

\parencite{BMG2018} \\

\parencite{BLS2011} 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is my .bib-File:

```
@online{BMG2018,
author = {{Bundesministerium für Gesundheit}},
shortauthor = {BMG},
title = {Gesund bleiben: Prävention und Gesundheitsförderung.},
date = {2018},
}

@booklet{BLS2011,
author = {{Bayerischer Landes-Sportverband e. V.}},
shortauthor = {BLS},
title = {Gesundheitssport im Verein},
date = {2011},
}
```

The following is what I get from this:
[image]

As you can see, the second time I cite the "Bayrischer Landes-Sportbund" (*BLS*), the citation looks completely different with the abbreviation not even in square brackets.

This is what I would expect to see:
[image]

It works, when I do the citations seperately the first time, e.g.

```
\parencite{BMG2018} \\
\parencite{BLS2011} \\

\parencite{BLS2011} \\

\parencite{BMG2018} \\

\parencite{BLS2011}
```

, but I need the initial double-citation.

**Question: Is this behaviour intended? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not, what is a possible workaround?**

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Open an issue in the biblatex-apa issue tracker.  Side remark: Don't use \\ so often. This only gives underfull warnings in the log.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/63

Comment: Nope, this is basically https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be the same bug as https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/24

The workaround

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

works here as well. But you may want to fix all cite commands so that you also need

```
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\nptextcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \global\booltrue{cbx:np}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}%
   \global\boolfalse{cbx:np}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}%
  {}
  {\iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\printdelim{nameyeardelim}%
      \printfield{postnote}}}

% doubtful if cite:post should be called at all
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:parens}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:volseen}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:titleinauthpos}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:editorinauthpos}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:in}%
      \global\let\blx@related@loop\@empty}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% doubtful if cite:post should be called at all
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
  {\list{}
   {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
     \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}\item}
  {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:parens}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:volseen}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:titleinauthpos}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:editorinauthpos}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:in}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {\item}
  {\endlist}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\bibsentence
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:author}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

You will then get

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. Do you have any suggestion how I can fix the natbib-equivalent commands \citep, \citet etc. when using biblatex with the *natbib=true* option?

Comment: @Pidrittel The `natbib` commands should be automatically fixed if you fix the standard commands. Does that not work for you?

Comment: No, it works. I did not even try it before I asked, sorry. Thank you very much again. :)